# How can I compare unicode type with str type in python of Chinese?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using python 2.7
for example:

```
a = u'你好'
b = '你好'
```

I tried following code but failed

```
print a.encode('UTF-8') == b #return False
```

How to compare them as equal?

Comment: I got `True`, How did you got `False` ?? Just try vice versa `b.decode('UTF-8') == a`

Comment: In python3 I get `False` with your exact code, but `True` when just doing the simple comparison `a==b`. In python2, your exact example outputs `True`.

Comment: Ni hao. When interacting with this in IDLE, if I try `a == b` I get a `UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal` message.

Comment: @M.T. in python3 `u'str'` and `'str'` both yields unicode, so `a == b` at the first place. No need to do anything afterwards. In python2 you need to `encode/decode`

Comment: You are in Python 3. `.encode` will give a `bytes` object, which evaluate to `False` when compared to a `str` object. In Python 3, `u"something"` will be of `str` type... there is not `unicode` type in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using `python3`, Both of the variables are `string` you don't need to change in to any of it. Simply compare both of them.

```
>>> a = u'你好'
>>> b = '你好'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'str'>
>>> a == b
True
```

if you are using `python2` your attempt will work.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely your Python source file isn't encoded in UTF-8. The variable `b` will contain whatever *bytes* are between those quotes. Those bytes will depend on the encoding. For example

```
# coding: utf-8
print repr("你好")
```

prints: `'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'`

Now if we save our source file as GB2312 and update the declaration:

```
# coding: GB2312
print repr("你好")
```

prints: `'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'`

In any case, if you have a byte array with text, you also need to know the encoding of those bytes, otherwise you can't reliably interpret them.

If you need UTF-8 bytes regardless of source file encoding, you can write `u'你好'.encode('utf-8')` will will always return `'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'`.